# iis manager binding vs host dns file?

Tags: dns, iis-manager

In the first place i should say that it might seem a bit weird but its a challenge to distinguish between the level of these configurations,for example ,say i want my `localhost` be accessible through `abc.com`, i know i should go through two steps:

1.use `iis` manager bindings

[image]

2.add `abc.com` to `dns` host file

```
127.0.0.1       abc.com
```

But is not clear for me level of these configs and what is each part's responsibility ?

Answer (score 0):

In a complete url request, steps as follows

1. User request abc.com.
2. DNS is request for abc.com.(That is why add abc.com to dns host file)
3. IP address for abc.com is returned.
4. Browser send request to the IP address.
5. IIS in server return site’s page.(That is why use iis manager bindings)

[Complete request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/overview-of-shared-hosting-deployment-using-application-request-routing-20)

[Why to use host file](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-a-hosts-file-to-improve-your-internet-experience/#:%7E:text=A%20Hosts%20file%20is%20a,and%20then%20a%20domain%20name.)